# Can't access to Ubuntu Interface when I open Ubuntu, just Terminal inteface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, root, user-interface

Please I have a serious problem using Ubuntu. I'm beginner in using Linux environment, I will try to explain the problem as good as can

The problem is that I can't have access to Linux interface

I have both systems Linux and Windows on the same computer. When I turn on the computer I choose which system I want to use, normally when I chose Linux, I can use the interface, the terminal... like Windows. But today when I tried to use Linux, it demands me my login and password and then only the terminal opened, I didn't have access to the interface. In other words, I can use just Terminal window and command lines, and I don't see any folders, I don't have this interface.

[image: Linux Interface]

Also, there's short msg in The terminal that says that there's a new version of Ubuntu 20.4, I wonder if I should update ! To solve the problem, if it's so please tell me the commands I should use to solve the problem.
Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.

Edit-1[image: When i first click to the power button]

[i wrote my login and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvatE.png)

[image: Terminal window opens !!]

Edit-1:
i just want to add some aditional informations , yesterday i uninstall some packages related to R and R studion ( statistical software )  , i don"t if this is related to the problem , also  i had some size problem that appears ( only 700 MO left..)

Comment: Is it possible you switched between sessions? Try CTRL-ALT-F7 to get back to your windowing display.

Comment: hello , Thank you for your answer  , i tried it , but unfortunately it dosen't work ( sorry for taking time to answer , its because i had to turn off windows session so  i can open linux to tried the solution )

Comment: try startx, and if doesn't start paste the errors. BTW. has nothing to do with upgrading, it's just telling you an upgrade is available.

Comment: Can you please explain to me p startx ?  or the command line i shoudl use

Comment: Yes on the commandline type startx that should startup X windows.

Comment: Does `sudo service lightdm start` make any difference? For newer versions of Ubuntu, try `sudo service gdm start` instead, or `sudo service gdm3 start`. Do any of these help?

Comment: Thank you for your comment , i tried the solution you said but unfotunately it dosen't work..

Comment: i also tried  startx , but it dosen't make any diffrence , but it shows a error msg says that file  /path/to/Xauthority does not exist ? , i edited the post with some additional informations that can make the situatiton more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you unintentionally uninstalled GUI dependencies, you can reinstall them.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

Then, enable GUI.

```
sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

Also, you can set to automatically start GUI on boot.

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Comment: Hello , Thank you very much for your answer , yes i tried : sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop and it works very well , Thank you very much