# Not able to acces ubuntu graphical interface just the terminal

Tags: ubuntu, gui

For some reason I started facing this error and I am not able to login in my pc any longer, I am just seeing the terminal, I can just login in the terminal every time I turn on my pc.

[image]

I followed this tutorial: [Can't access to Ubuntu Interface when I open Ubuntu, just Terminal inteface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616001/cant-access-to-ubuntu-interface-when-i-open-ubuntu-just-terminal-inteface) but I got with sudo apt-get update:

[image]

Not sure what I have to do, because I am not able to reinstall ubuntu neiher just seeing the terminal forever.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/91595/1086345)

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl get-default`? And what happens if you run `sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target` or `startx`? Please update your question and don't answer in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem when upgrading to ubuntu 22.04 except my terminal didn't have sudo. I'm not sure what caused it but I fixed it by deleting all directories but home and then replacing them from a usb installer. No guarantee but if you don't have anything important outside your home directory it wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: Recommending a complete re-install is rather drastic. Booting from a live image and then installing/configuring sudo is much easier.

Comment: Reinstalling sudo didn't work and sudo wasn't the only problem in my case. I had nothing important outside my home folder so a whole reinstall was a ton easier than trying to diagnose and fix all the specific problems.